# Login to sqlite doesn't work (using PDO)

Tags: php, pdo

could you help me to check it out? Is there anything wrong here? It couldn't be able to reach to file.sqlite. I'm wondering why. and also when it's successful, it wont direct to phptesting.php.

HTML (testing.php)

```
<div class="box">
    <form action="login.php" id="loginForm" method="post">
        <p> User ID : <input type ="text" name="userID"> </p>
        <p> Password : <input type ="password" name="password"> </p>
        <p> <input type="submit" value="Login"> </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

PHP (login.php)

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once('session.php');
require_once('pdoDB.class.php');

$db = pdoDB::getConnection();
$session = Session::getInstance();

$userID = $_POST['userID'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if($userID == '') {
        echo ('Please Enter Your Username');
}

$userSQL = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE userid =: '$userID' AND password =: '$password'";
$query = $db->prepare($userSQL);
$query->execute (array ($userID,$password));
$result = $query->fetchObject();

if (empty($result)) {
        echo ('Not Logged In!');
} else {
        echo('Logged In');
        header('location:phptesting.php');
}
?>
```

pdoDB.class.php

```
<?php
class pdoDB {

    private static $dbConnection = null;

    private function __construct() {
    }

    private function __clone() {
    }

    public static function getConnection() {
        if ( !self::$dbConnection ) {
            try {
                self::$dbConnection = new PDO( "sqlite:/file.sqlite");
                self::$dbConnection->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            }
            catch( PDOException $e ) {

                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
        return self::$dbConnection;
    }
}
?>
```

and session.php

```
<?php

Class Session {

    private static $getInstance;

    private function __construct(){

        session_start();
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (!isset(self::$getInstance)) {
            self::$getInstance = new Session();
        }
        return self::$getInstance;
    }

    public function setProperty($key,$val) {
        $_SESSION[$key] = $val;
    }

    public function getProperty($key) {
        $returnValue = "";
        if(isset($_SESSION[$key])) {
            $returnValue = $_SESSION[$key];
        }
        return $returnValue;
    }
}


?>
```

Any problem?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing it, but I don't see a reference to `file.sqlite` in your code.

Comment: You're using prepared queries and have no reference at all to SQLite in your code. Are you sure you're using SQLite?

Comment: Yes I'm very sure, I'm using file.sqlite. Anyway, could you tell me how to retrieve the file.sqlite from that page? and also another problem is when i click the button Login, it won't go to login.php to get the value and won't redirect to phptesting.php. ANy ideas?

Comment: `echo` and  `header` won't work, visit the [manual](http://php.net/header)

Comment: @pce I've deleted that `echo`, just `header`. it still doesn't work at all too..

Comment: did you fixed your SQL? You have to fix the placeholders.

Comment: SQL wasn't working. Where should I put the placeholder? @pce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't put quotes on your placeholders, nor use php variable, should just be `:name`.

try changing

```
"SELECT * FROM user WHERE userid =: '$userID' AND password =: '$password'";
```

to

```
$userSQL = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE userid =:userID AND password = :password";
```

Then execute it the right way since your are using named placeholders:

```
$query->execute(array (':userID' => $userID,
                       ':password' => $password
));
```

---

Alternatively you can use question marks

```
$userSQL = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE userid =? AND password =?";
$query = $db->prepare($userSQL);
$query->execute(array($userID,$password));
```

Comment: Yeah thanks, I just realised that. I fixed that. But the problem it's not connecting to file.sqlite and when I click the button, it ended to login.php. if it works, shld redirect to testing.php.. any ideas?

Comment: @Anthosiast `header('location: phptesting.php');` whatch out for that space, between `:` and `phptesting.php`

Comment: yeah, i've removed that space. it's still doesn't work. I dont know why is that. I still can't point something wrong.

Comment: @meta forget to tag you. haha

Comment: @Anthosiast try removing that echo `echo('Logged In');`

Comment: I've just removed `echo('Logged In');` few seconds ago, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52064/discussion-between-meda-and-anthosiast)